# Identificar o ID/Número de cada Shape de Caixa de Texto

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Comecei a usar o VBA para o powerpoint e precisava começar a referenciar no meu código cada Shape dentro da apresentação. Mas não sei qual é o nome de cada Shape para referenciar. Como sei que uma caixa de texto é o shape(1), shape(2) ou shape(40).

Detalhe, eu estou trabalhando com powerpoints prontos, ou seja, não sei a ordem com que cada shape foi criada.

Existe algum lugar que eu possa consultar o número de cada Shape?

Comment: Qual é a alteração que você quer fazer em cada Shape? É uma alteração massificada, ou individual? Neste caso, depende do quê (conteúdo do shape, cor, forma)? Esclareça melhor a pergunta!

Comment: Na verdade, eu gostaria de alterar tanto texto e cor, bem como substituir um shape por outro quando necessário. Minha idéia é gerar um material publicitário de forma automática conforme algumas condições definidas pelo o usuário, mas para isso preciso alterar diversas informações do slide

Comment: Ainda não estou entendendo bem uma coisa: você quer:
(1) em tempo de execução, sem supervisão humana, descobrir o tipo e a referência de todos os Shapes e aplicar automaticamente mudanças em alguns deles, ou você quer (2) enquanto está programando o código, com um arquivo-exemplo aberto, descobrir como referenciar uma ou outra forma que você vê naquele arquivo específico, para experimentar o que você consegue fazer com AQUELA caixa de texto DAQUELA apresentação powerpoint que está aberta à sua frente?

Comment: Estou querendo fazer o 2. Dada uma apresentação, alterar um Shape específico conforme as instruções do meu código. Para isso, preciso saber referenciar cada shape da apresentação e é isso que não estou conseguindo

Answer (score 0):

## Caixas de Texto

Se você deseja obter somente de caixas de texto como da imagem abaixo:

[image: Teste]

A propriedade `.HasTextFrame` pode ser usada num loop em todas apresentações e shapes.

#### Código

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes

            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Debug.Print "Texto: " & shp.TextFrame2.TextRange & " " _
                ; "ID: " & shp.Id & " " _
                ; "Nome: " & shp.Name
            End If

Next shp
Next sld
```

## Todos os Shapes

Já para todos os Shapes da apresentação, você pode obter o Tipo, ID e Nome.

#### Código

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sr As Series
Dim txt As Chart

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                Debug.Print "Tipo: " & shp.Type & " " _
                ; "ID: " & shp.Id & " " _
                ; "Nome: " & shp.Name
Next shp
Next sld
```

## Lista de Tipos

```
+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
|         Nome         | Valor |            Descrição             |
+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
| msoAutoShape         |     1 | AutoForma.                       |
| msoCallout           |     2 | Texto Explicativo.               |
| msoCanvas            |    20 | Tela.                            |
| msoChart             |     3 | Gráfico.                         |
| msoComment           |     4 | Comentário.                      |
| msoContentApp        |    27 | Suplemento de conteúdo do Office |
| msoDiagram           |    21 | Diagrama.                        |
| msoEmbeddedOLEObject |     7 | Objeto OLE incorporado.          |
| msoFormControl       |     8 | Controle de formulário.          |
| msoFreeform          |     5 | Forma Livre.                     |
| msoGraphic           |    28 | Elemento gráfico                 |
| msoGroup             |     6 | Grupo.                           |
| msoIgxGraphic        |    24 | Gráfico SmartArt                 |
| msoInk               |    22 | Tinta                            |
| msoInkComment        |    23 | Comentário à tinta               |
| msoLine              |     9 | Linha                            |
| msoLinkedGraphic     |    29 | Gráfico vinculado                |
| msoLinkedOLEObject   |    10 | Objeto OLE vinculado             |
| msoLinkedPicture     |    11 | Imagem vinculada                 |
| msoMedia             |    16 | Mídia                            |
| msoOLEControlObject  |    12 | Objeto de controle OLE           |
| msoPicture           |    13 | Imagem                           |
| msoPlaceholder       |    14 | Espaço reservado                 |
| msoScriptAnchor      |    18 | Âncora de script                 |
| msoShapeTypeMixed    |    -2 | Tipo de forma misto              |
| msoTable             |    19 | Tabela                           |
| msoTextBox           |    17 | Caixa de texto                   |
| msoTextEffect        |    15 | Efeito de texto                  |
| msoWebVideo          |    26 | Vídeo da Web                     |
+----------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
```

> Obs. 1: Veja [A documentação de Shapes para mais informações](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-object-powerpoint)
>
> Obs. 2: Para visualizar o que é impresso com o comando `Debug.Print`, é preciso habilitar a janela de Verificação Imediata.